# on 'click' firing before click

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

Why does this console print when I haven't clicked the Leaflet layer? As I read this, the function `onClick` fires and logs to the console when I click the the point layer. But the console logs on page refresh. billboardLayer and bannerLayer are both JS objects.

html:

```
<body>

  <div id='map'></div>
  <div id='footer'>
    <div><img src="\data\images\SC811new2.png" class="footer-img">
        <h1>Average Rent in Every US County</h1>
    </div>
    <p id='imageTest'></p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var js_files = {
      billboardLayer: {
        source: billboardLocations,
        color: '#1f78b4'
      },
      bannerLayer: {
        source: bannerLocations,
        color: '#ff2700'
      }
    };
    var geojsonLayers = {};
    for (file in js_files) {
      //console.log(js_files[file].source)
      //console.log(js_files[file].color)
      geojsonLayers[file] = L.geoJson(js_files[file].source, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
          return L.circleMarker(latlng)//.on('click', onClick);
        },
        style: function (feature) {
          return {
            fillColor: js_files[file].color,
            weight: 0,
            fillOpacity: 0.75,
            radius: 10
          }
        },
         onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
           var images = layer.feature.properties.imageFile;
           //console.log(images);
           layer.on('click', onClick(images));
         }
      }).addTo(map);
    }
function onClick(images) {
        console.log(images);
        //var x = document.getElementById('imageTest');
        //x.innerHTML = '<img src="data/images/LCWASD -Lancaster 2.jpg"/>';
        //console.log(x)
        //<img src="\data\images\LCWASD -Lancaster.jpg" id="imageTest">
        //"<img src='something' onmouseover='change(\"ex1\")' />"
      };
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: because you are executing the function.... You are not assigning it to click

Comment: layer.on('click', onClick(images)) that should execute, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By calling `onClick(images)` you are invoking the function. You just need to pass a reference. E.g. `onClick.bind(this, images)` so it should be `layer.on('click', onClick.bind(this, images));`

As it's only a reference you would be passing, it doesn't get invoked until the callback of the click handler is executed, i.e. when you click

Comment: That did not work, sorry. I also don't totally understand what you're referring to.